# How to stop tornado web app when there is no connection?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I want to start a temporary web app when there is a connection comes, stop it when there is no connection and timeout.
I use python tornado WebSocketHandler, anyone can help? An example will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you will only ever have one connection, you can call IOLoop.current().stop() from your WebSocketHandler's on_close method.  If you need more than one you can increment a counter in open(), decrement it in on_close(), and stop the IOLoop when it reaches zero.